# A good heatmapping plugin for WordPress? (No 3rd-party services please)

Tags: plugins

I am hoping someone in this group can help me. We’re interested in
obtaining more information on where people click on the site, ideally in
as simple a way as possible. I looked up “heatmaps” on WP, and found
some plug-ins, we want to avoid third-party services such as Crazyegg,
so “WP Super Heatmap” jumped out (five stars, “simple,” etc.). Anyone
have experience with this or other click-map plug-ins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I have used [ClickHeat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) which has (seemingly third party) [plugin for it in repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-clickheat-intergration-plugin/), but I just integrated it manually.